# Do the UI element properties of an application change if you execute our elements in different devices?

Tags: java, element, appium

Does the UI element properties of an application change if you execute our elements in different devices.

If I am executing my test script in different device for example on iPad and iPhone then does the element properties changes for the same application .For example do I have different element properties for the Login button if I execute my script in different devices?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the only properties difference is the location and size of elements due to automatic UI scaling. Of course it's possible that some UI elements change completely on the different screen sizes by design. It's basically up to the app developers to make the UI scale so it's all in their hands.

Other properties like name and label values should be the same, unless the app has been coded to use some kind of dynamic naming values for some reason.

An uncommon change that I think is possible also is the xpath value changing due to the app UI being somehow dynamically built. This kind of behaviour could happen with some cross-platform app frameworks, but I don't have any examples to give so this part should be taken with a grain of salt.